# Strange circle pattern on the ground in Don't Starve

Tags: dont-starve

So I was wandering around the world and stumbled upon this thing:

[image]

Honestly, it looks way too manmade for me not to question it. So does this have any relevance to anything in the game or is it just random?

Comment: Is this in sandbox mode, or adventure mode?

Comment: Adventure mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Crop Circles](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Orion76/The_Mystery_of_the_Mini_Crop_Circles) have many speculations.

- According to [some sources](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Orion76/The_Mystery_of_the_Mini_Crop_Circles), there are no answers.
- According to [others](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/27524-fairy-rings-and-crop-circles/?p=318576), it was simply a glitch that was kept as a Set Piece.

[Fairy Rings](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/topic/14516-weird-red-mushroom-generation-pattern/) (circles of things, say, mushrooms) are a similar topic.

Answer (score -4):

if you stay there for a minute you will get a great guardian

Comment: Do you have a source for this?  It sounds a bit like an unsubstantiated rumor.